# On the sum of digits of $f(n)$

Tags: number-theory

This is probably wel known, so please let me know. Let $s(n)$ be the sum of all digits of the integer $n$ (in base 10). Consider a polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients. I want to show that for any large enough $n$, $s(f(n)) \leq s(n!)$. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Just an idea: $s(n)$ is bounded by $9(\log_{10}n+1)$ and you have that $\log_{10}n^k=k\log_{10}n$. So $s(f(n))$ should be bounded by $C\log n$ for some constant.  $\log n! \ge \log e^n=nc$. So asymptotically it should be true, the only problem is that $n!$ could have a lot of $0$, I don't know how to bound this number.

Comment: According to a [paper/preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4912) by Carlo Sanna around a year ago, for every base $b$, there is a constant $C_b$ such that for every integer $n > e$, the sum of digits of $n!$ in base $b$ is bounded from below by $C_b\log(n)\cdot\log\log\log(n)$.

Comment: Well, that bound is just enaugh to prove the statement.

Comment: Also see http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1133839